# react native all Axios methods not working second

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I try page isfocused work this method.this is working and go to getuserform method.But Axios
does not request again.I can't see any response or exception.I get old data again.

```
useEffect(() => {

        dispatch(getUserForm(id))

    }, [id, isFocused])
```

```
export const getUserForm = (userId) => {
     return dispatch => {
        axios.get(`${APIURL}/Form/${userId}`)
            .then(response => {
                dispatch({
                    type: 'GET_USER_FORM',
                    userForm: response.data,
                })
            })
            .catch(err => console.error)

    }
}
```

Comment: How does `isFocused` change?

Comment: import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native' it is a navigation prop.İf navigation route change is focused change.

Comment: How did you try to change the `isFocused` change?